# Deleting on record from table every 5 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete one record every 5 seconds and have a cron job for it too.  But once the cron starts it deletes all records at once.

Whether I use sleep 5 here or not it does not effect in execution

The used code is below.

```
mysql_select_db($database_xm, $xm);
$query_ex = "SELECT * FROM table";
$ex = mysql_query($query_ex, $xm) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ex = mysql_fetch_assoc($ex);

$RecordCount=mysql_num_rows($ex); 

for ($l=0;$l<=$RecordCount;$l++) {

mysql_select_db($database_xm, $xm);
$query_ss = "delete from table2 limit 1";
$ss = mysql_query($query_ss, $xm) or die(mysql_error());


    sleep(5);   
    ob_flush(); 

}
```

How do I delete one record every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply pick a record and identify it from the information you already have in `$row_ex`? This way you can also control the order in which records are deleted.

```
for ($l=0;$l<=$RecordCount;$l++) {
    $row = $row_ex[$l];
    $query_ss = "delete from table2 WHERE id = ".$row['id']; // EXAMPLE
    $ss = mysql_query($query_ss, $xm) or die(mysql_error());
    sleep(5);   
    ob_flush(); 
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but here I don't have an id to work on as the records once delete the table is not truncated.  Are there other ways to do it.

Comment: @Jean: Well, don't you care about the *order* in which the records are deleted? And if you do, how do you order them?

Comment: It is a table where I dump certain data, BUT I have to delete one every 5 seconds.  else I have to truncate it.  That would be a viable solution and use `where id ='$l'`

Comment: It worked..I truncated the table, used the record count as the id value...And the cron job works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

The cron min exec time is 1m, you have to make infinitive loop, inside there must me sleep(5) after every loop

Comment: It is not the cron loop, but when it hits inside the for loop. It deletes the entire records.

Comment: I see. But you have $query_ss = "delete from table2 limit 1";
So substitute the for loop with while(true) { ... }.
PS: YOu are selecting from table, then loop over the results and delete from table2. Relations between both ?

Answer (score -2):

SET ROWCOUNT 1 will limit the number of rows to 1

For example:

-- Sets limit of rows to 1
SET ROWCOUNT 1

delete from table2

-- Sets limit back to default
SET ROWCOUNT 0

Would do it.

Comment: You would even do your wait statement in SQL

Comment: I have set the limit to 1, if that is what you are indicating?

Comment: MySQL doesn't provide `SET ROWCOUNT`, it provides `LIMIT` instead of it.